# How to trigger file input in repeating form

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a div with dynamic repeating form to change image of a repeating div based on respective id, when a div image is clicked i want to trigger file input for clicked div.
contents are loaded into div(image-container) with jquery post request.

**HTML**

```
<div id="image-container"></div>

//repating dynamic form
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):?>

<div class="image">
    <form name="image_change">
        <img src=".." class="image_change"/>
        <input name="image" type="file" />
        <input name="id" type="hidden" />
        <input name="edit" type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#image-container').on('click', 'form[name=image_change] .image_change', function(){
    $(this).find('input[name=image]').trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

This works only when form is not repeating, how can i make it work with repeating form.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by repeating form?

Comment: He means he has more than 1 forms on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have multiple forms with the same name and only the first one is recognized.

Remove name attribute from the form:

```
<div class="image">
    <form>
        <img src=".." class="image_change"/>
        <input name="image" type="file" />
        <input name="id" type="hidden" />
        <input name="edit" type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

and modify the js code to the following

```
$(document).on('click', 'form .image_change', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('input[name=image]').trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

if you need to differentiate the form add ids to the forms.

Comment: Image result are based on database, and since while loop, i cannot show the demo.

Comment: Instead of using the attribute selector, give different ids to the input element like imag1, image2 and so on using PHP or any server side scripting you use and then make the changes in the jQuery code.

Comment: @Deepak Kamat if i do it like that than i have to write separate jQuey codes for each image ids.

Comment: Put multiple selectors in your jQuery 
`$('#image1, #image2, #image3')`

Comment: @Deepak: this can be replaced with `$("img[id^='image']")`

Comment: @AlecTMH your example not trigging file click.

Comment: @Deepak the problem is still in finding which id is current, like `$(this).find('input[name=image]').trigger('click');` this problem is only occuring on click trigger event for file, for anything else its working fine.

Comment: `$(this).parent().find("input[name=image]").trigger('click');`

Comment: @AlecTMH still same problem not triggering file click event.

Comment: @AlecTMH still same problem not triggering file click event on clicking image in your demo it only alerts src name of file, file trigger event occurs on default browse option.

Comment: @AlecTMH does your demo working in your browser, i.e are you getting file triggred on clicking image not by browse option, i have tried in firefox and IE its not working here.

Comment: Yes, it's working, file is triggered when I click on the image

Comment: @AlecTMH Its not working here, i appriciate your time and input, thanks a lot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22262/discussion-between-alectmh-and-tall-boy)